# Query with "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE"

Tags: t-sql, sybase, sap-ase

I have a code:

```
DECLARE @a char(4)    
Select @a=field_name   
FROM table_name
where field='abc'    

CASE @a
WHEN '2016' THEN 
SELECT 'YES'
ELSE    
SELECT 'No'
END CASE
```

The error is:

> Incorrect syntax near keyword 'CASE'

What is the problem?

Comment: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/sqlug588.htm

Comment: To close your CASE statement, just use `END` - not `END CASE`

Answer (score 1):

This works with MSSQL:

```
DECLARE @a char(4)    
Select @a=field_name
FROM table_name
where field='abc'

IF @a = '2016'
SELECT 'YES'
ELSE    
SELECT 'No'
```

Or use this:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN field_name = '2016' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'No' END
FROM table_name
WHERE field='abc'
```

Comment: Last comment doesn't work. Incorrect syntax near keyword 'SELECT. I need some other solution with CASE.

Comment: Sorry, I saw too late it was a Sybase question. The code above works in MSSQL.
Based on the Michael's link, try adding a name for the CASE, e.g. SELECT "Result" = CASE WHEN field_name...